# ¿por qué no imprime una sentencia JTextPane.print()?

Tags: java

Cuando imprimo un JtextArea no hay problema. ¿Por qué tengo problemas con el JTextPane.print()?  A continuación les dejo el código:

```
            Imprimir pagina1=new  Imprimir(ventana,1);
            JTextPane paginaImprimir=pagina1.darPanel();
            try {
                paginaImprimir.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

le dejo la aqui abajo la clase Imprimir:

```
            public class Imprimir {
            private MarcoFinal datos;
            private JPanel arriba;
            private JTextPane pagina;
            public Imprimir(MarcoFinal datos1, int j) {
            datos=datos1;


            arriba=new JPanel();
            arriba.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
            pagina=new JTextPane();



             if(j==1){ 
            pagina.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel intermedioArriba= new JPanel();
            intermedioArriba.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
            RedimensionarIcon imagenIcono=new 
            RedimensionarIcon("C:/Users/Julio/Desktop/programas de java 1/ERP4/Jesus.jpg",50,50);
            JLabel etiquetaImagen=new JLabel(imagenIcono.darImagen());
            JLabel etiquetaNombreOptica=new JLabel("Optica Luz");
            JLabel etiquetaCiudad=new JLabel("Santiago");
            JLabel etiquetaDireccion=new JLabel("Pedro de Valdivia 3482");
            intermedioArriba.add(etiquetaImagen);

             arriba.add(etiquetaNombreOptica);
             arriba.add(etiquetaCiudad);
             arriba.add(etiquetaDireccion);
             intermedioArriba.add(arriba);
             pagina.add(intermedioArriba,BorderLayout.NORTH);
             JTextArea areaImpresion=new JTextArea(3,5);
             String escrito=" Nombre: "+datos.getNorte().darNombre()+"\n rut = "+datos.getNorte().darRut()+"\n producto="+datos.getNorte().darProducto()+"\n cantidad= "+datos.getNorte().darCantidad();
             areaImpresion.setText(escrito);
             pagina.add(areaImpresion,BorderLayout.CENTER);
             JButton boton=new JButton("imprimir");
             pagina.add(boton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

}

 public JTextPane darPanel() {
     return pagina;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a especificar el tipo de contenido con `paginaImprimir.setContentType("text/html");` antes de imprimir. A mi me solucionó el problema, no sé si será tu caso.